# building models with foreignkey and OnetoOne relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-models

I am trying to make `models` for my project.

1) This includes a `model` for `CarInfo`, which holds details about the car, such as year, make and model.

```
class CarInfo(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    make=models.OneToOneField('Manufacturer')
```

2) for the car make, I am thinking of the following model;

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    CARMAKER_CHOICES=(('Toyota','TOYOTA'),
                    ('ford','FORD'),
                    ('mazda','MAZDA'), ('Honda','HONDA'), )
    carmaker=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CARMAKER_CHOICES)
```

3) for the car model, I want to make the following model, but I do not know how to implement it.

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
    maker=models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    # if the manufacturerer is Toyota, the different models are
    MODEL_CHOICES=(('Prius','PRIUS'),
                    ('Camry','CAMRY'),
                    ('Rav4','RAV4'),)
    carmodel=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=MODEL_CHOICES)
```

As you can see the `CarModel` is dependent on the manufacturer and hence car model choices will be entirely different. How should I build a model in this case or I am open to better alternative models.

Answer (score 0):

Django alone cannot conditionally display/use choices based on another. Probably the easiest approach would be to use Javascript/jQuery on your page to display the choices based on previous selection.

Alternatively, you could also look at using Django's [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) to show the form at multiple stages.

Either way, this will have to be done at the form/template level and not in the model itself.

#### UPDATE

There's no way to *dynamically* populate fields/attributes based on another field in the current model. Additionally, the car models that correspond to their manufacturers will have to be stored somewhere. Currently in `MODEL_CHOICES`, but as you've explained you want this to be populated based on the manufacturer plus it might become a hassle to keep updating tuples going forward so it's best put in the database.

So if we changed the `CarModel` and `CarInfo` models slightly,

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
    carmaker = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    carmodel = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CarInfo(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    make = models.OneToOneField('Manufacturer')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

it could hold that information for us like so:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  |  carmaker  |  carmodel  |
+-----+------------+------------+
|  1  |   Toyota   |   Prius    |
|  2  |   Toyota   |   Camry    |
...
```

Then if we ever need to filter/restrict the models to their manufacturers via `CarInfo`, say in a form, it can be done so with a simple query:

```
class CarInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CarInfo

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CarInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['model'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CarModel.objects.filter(carmodel=self.instance.carmodel))
```

Again, this would be much simpler to do via Javascript or jQuery in the template/browser. If you are not opposed to using third-party libraries there are some that add functionality around models as choice fields: [dj-choices](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dj.choices/), [django-smart-select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) and [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1968/) django snippet were a few I found.

Comment: I am not concerned with form at the moment, I am interested in building a clear models and relationship that establish them.

Comment: To me, using choices implies that you are thinking about form(s) since a _choice_ is to be made by a user. Still, this will have to be done in the form/template, not the model. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I am looking for an optimal way, it could be totally different from my way of using choices (which could be totally wrong). please feel free to come up with a model that you think works better.